Upgrade to ubuntu 24.02 LTS gave firmware issue
So, a couple of months back I did regular updates on my personal Ubuntu laptop, which included a version upgrade. This did some firmware upgrades and something went wrong with efi. I can't exactly remember what, because I didn't really have the time at the time and I was mainly using my work pc. I could still log in, but gnome wouldn't start up. I could boot in recovery mode however.
Anyway, I was trying to fix it in recovery mode today and I copied something from StackExchange without clearly understanding it and now all I can do is a memtest.
I made myself a boot repair USB to try and fix it, but no luck here. It reports the following:
boot-repair-4ppa2074                                              [20241025_1535]

============================= Boot Repair Summary ==============================






Recommended repair: ____________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility will reinstall the grub-efi of
sdb4,
using the following options:  sdb1/boot/efi
Additional repair will be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s use-standard-efi-file restore-efi-backups


rm /mnt/boot-sav/sdb1/efi/Boot/bootx64.efi
mv /mnt/boot-sav/sdb1/efi/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi /mnt/boot-sav/sdb1/efi/Boot/bootx64.efi
/dev/sdb4/boot/efi not empty
Mount /dev/sdb1 on /mnt/boot-sav/sdb4/boot/efi

===================== Reinstall the grub-efi of /dev/sdb4 ======================

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/sdb4 grub-install --version
grub-install (GRUB) 2.12~rc1-10ubuntu4.2
modprobe: FATAL: Module efivars not found in directory /lib/modules/5.15.0-76-generic
chroot /mnt/boot-sav/sdb4 modprobe efivars

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/sdb4 efibootmgr -v before grub install
BootCurrent: 0005
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0005,0002,0003,0004,0001,0000
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager  VenHw(99e275e7-75a0-4b37-a2e6-c5385e6c00cb)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}...e................
Boot0001* Windows Boot Manager  VenHw(99e275e7-75a0-4b37-a2e6-c5385e6c00cb)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}....................
Boot0002* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,c96eee69-b829-4c33-b6a0-529fd7aa0140,0x800,0x32000)/File(EFIMICROSOFTBOOTBOOTMGFW.EFI)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}....................
Boot0003* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,c96eee69-b829-4c33-b6a0-529fd7aa0140,0x800,0x32000)/File(EFIUBUNTUGRUBX64.EFI)
Boot0004* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,c96eee69-b829-4c33-b6a0-529fd7aa0140,0x800,0x32000)/File(EFIUBUNTUSHIMX64.EFI)..BO
Boot0005* UEFI: HEMA_8G HEMA_8GB, Partition 1   PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(6,0)/HD(1,MBR,0x77d54e,0x80,0xf43f40)..BO

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/sdb4 uname -r
5.15.0-76-generic

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/sdb4 grub-install --efi-directory=/boot/efi --target=x86_64-efi
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
grub-install: warning: EFI variables cannot be set on this system.
grub-install: warning: You will have to complete the GRUB setup manually.
Installation finished. No error reported.
df /dev/sdb1
mv /mnt/boot-sav/sdb4/boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi /mnt/boot-sav/sdb4/boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi
cp /mnt/boot-sav/sdb4/boot/efi/efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /mnt/boot-sav/sdb4/boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/sdb4 grub-install --efi-directory=/boot/efi --target=x86_64-efi
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
grub-install: warning: EFI variables cannot be set on this system.
grub-install: warning: You will have to complete the GRUB setup manually.
Installation finished. No error reported.

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/sdb4 efibootmgr -v after grub install
BootCurrent: 0005
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0005,0002,0003,0004,0001,0000
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager  VenHw(99e275e7-75a0-4b37-a2e6-c5385e6c00cb)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}...e................
Boot0001* Windows Boot Manager  VenHw(99e275e7-75a0-4b37-a2e6-c5385e6c00cb)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}....................
Boot0002* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,c96eee69-b829-4c33-b6a0-529fd7aa0140,0x800,0x32000)/File(EFIMICROSOFTBOOTBOOTMGFW.EFI)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}....................
Boot0003* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,c96eee69-b829-4c33-b6a0-529fd7aa0140,0x800,0x32000)/File(EFIUBUNTUGRUBX64.EFI)
Boot0004* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,c96eee69-b829-4c33-b6a0-529fd7aa0140,0x800,0x32000)/File(EFIUBUNTUSHIMX64.EFI)..BO
Boot0005* UEFI: HEMA_8G HEMA_8GB, Partition 1   PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(6,0)/HD(1,MBR,0x77d54e,0x80,0xf43f40)..BO
Warning: NVram was not modified.

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/sdb4 update-grub
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/grub/grub-sort-version", line 4, in <module>
import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/grub/grub-sort-version", line 4, in <module>
import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/grub/grub-sort-version", line 4, in <module>
import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'
Found memtest86+ 64bit EFI image: /boot/memtest86+x64.efi
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/sdb1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...

Unhide GRUB boot menu in sdb4/boot/grub/grub.cfg

Boot successfully repaired.

You can now reboot your computer.
Please do not forget to make your UEFI firmware boot on the Ubuntu 24.04 LTS entry (sdb1/efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi file) !
If your computer reboots directly into Windows, try to change the boot order in your UEFI firmware.
If your UEFI firmware does not allow to change the boot order, change the default boot entry of the Windows bootloader.
For example you can boot into Windows, then type the following command in an admin command prompt:
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi


============================ Boot Info After Repair ============================

 => Grub2 (v2.00) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 1 of 
    the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
    for /boot/grub. It also embeds following components:
    
    modules
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    fshelp ext2 part_msdos biosdisk search_fs_uuid
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    config script
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    search.fs_uuid 31593fa6-7183-49a1-8c29-fc4d2fb78d37 root hd1,msdos5 
    set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
    
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 => Grub2 (v1.99-2.00) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb and looks at sector 
    1 of the same hard drive for core.img, but core.img can not be found at 
    this location.
 => Syslinux MBR (5.00 and higher) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdc.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       Extended Partition
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sda5: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sdb1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi /efi/Boot/bootx64.efi 
                       /efi/Boot/grubx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/MokManager.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi 
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi

sdb2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sdb3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  Windows 10 or 11
    Boot files:        /bootmgr /Windows/System32/winload.exe

sdb4: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  Grub2 (v1.99-2.00)
    Boot sector info:  Grub2 (v1.99-2.00) is installed in the boot sector of 
                       sdb4 and looks at sector 158415360 of the same hard 
                       drive for core.img, but core.img can not be found at 
                       this location.
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab /etc/default/grub 
                       /boot/grub/i386-pc/core.img

sdc1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  SYSLINUX 6.04
    Boot sector info:  Syslinux looks at sector 32784 of /dev/sdc1 for its 
                       second stage. The integrity check of Syslinux failed. 
                       No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /syslinux.cfg 
                       /efi/boot/bootx64.efi /efi/boot/grubx64.efi 
                       /efi/boot/mmx64.efi /ldlinux.sys

sdc2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 


================================ 2 OS detected =================================

OS#1:   Ubuntu 24.04 LTS on sdb4
OS#2:   Windows 10 or 11 on sdb3

================================ Host/Hardware =================================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Video: Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520] from Intel Corporation
Live-session OS is Linuxmint 64-bit (Linux Mint 21.2, victoria, x86_64)

===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS/UEFI firmware: 5.11(5.11) from American Megatrends Inc.
The firmware is EFI-compatible, and is set in EFI-mode for this live-session.
SecureBoot disabled (confirmed by mokutil).
BootCurrent: 0005
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0005,0002,0003,0004,0001,0000
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager  VenHw(99e275e7-75a0-4b37-a2e6-c5385e6c00cb)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}...e................
Boot0001* Windows Boot Manager  VenHw(99e275e7-75a0-4b37-a2e6-c5385e6c00cb)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}....................
Boot0002* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,c96eee69-b829-4c33-b6a0-529fd7aa0140,0x800,0x32000)/File(\EFI\MICROSOFT\BOOT\BOOTMGFW.EFI)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}....................
Boot0003* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,c96eee69-b829-4c33-b6a0-529fd7aa0140,0x800,0x32000)/File(\EFI\UBUNTU\GRUBX64.EFI)
Boot0004* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,c96eee69-b829-4c33-b6a0-529fd7aa0140,0x800,0x32000)/File(\EFI\UBUNTU\SHIMX64.EFI)..BO
Boot0005* UEFI: HEMA_8G HEMA_8GB, Partition 1   PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(6,0)/HD(1,MBR,0x77d54e,0x80,0xf43f40)..BO

596872cda30b2b89e148b9a9060c4ccd   sdb1/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi
596872cda30b2b89e148b9a9060c4ccd   sdb1/Boot/bootx64.efi
596872cda30b2b89e148b9a9060c4ccd   sdb1/Boot/grubx64.efi
ba8a7979ac57f1c0c307ef94d1020eb8   sdb1/ubuntu/MokManager.efi
596872cda30b2b89e148b9a9060c4ccd   sdb1/ubuntu/grubx64.efi
ded965934506efb38a6dcb9ac5b2b79e   sdb1/ubuntu/shimx64.efi
8561c3e35368c746fd3cf8b9c0e71663   sdb1/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
8f87a2fbaaa64d7b22150e1881b9eb87   sdb1/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi

============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

sda : notGPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has-noESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, no-os, no-wind,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes
sdb : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has---ESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    has-win,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes
sdc : notGPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has-noESP,  usb-disk,   not-mmc, no-os, no-wind,    128 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

sda1    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   end-after-100GB
sda5    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   end-after-100GB
sdb1    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far
sdb3    : is-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far
sdb4    : is-os,    64, apt-get,    signed grub-efi ,   grub2,  grub-install,   grubenv-ok, update-grub,    end-after-100GB
sdc2    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

sda1    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda5    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sdb1    : is---ESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sdb3    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  haswinload, no-recov-nor-hid,   bootmgr,    notwinboot
sdb4    : isnotESP, fstab-has-goodEFI,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sdc2    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

sda1    : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda
sda5    : maybesepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda
sdb1    : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sdb
sdb3    : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sdb
sdb4    : not--sepboot, with-boot,  fstab-without-boot, not-sep-usr,    with--usr,  fstab-without-usr,  std-grub.d, sdb
sdc2    : maybesepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sdc

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk sda: 232.89 GiB, 250059350016 bytes, 488397168 sectors
Disk identifier: 0xd039e563
     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
sda1            2048 244142672 244140625 116.4G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
sda2       244144126 488396799 244252674 116.5G  5 Extended
sda5       244144128 488396799 244252672 116.5G 83 Linux
Disk sdb: 111.79 GiB, 120034123776 bytes, 234441648 sectors
Disk identifier: 339354E2-756E-4495-919E-6B722FE806A4
         Start       End   Sectors  Size Type
sdb1       2048    206847    204800  100M EFI System
sdb2     206848    468991    262144  128M Microsoft reserved
sdb3     720896 111456255 110735360 52.8G Microsoft basic data
sdb4  111458304 234432511 122974208 58.6G Linux filesystem
Disk sdc: 7.63 GiB, 8195719168 bytes, 16007264 sectors
Disk identifier: 0x0077d54e
     Boot    Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
sdc1  *         128 16007103 16006976  7.6G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
sdc2       16007166 16007228       63 31.5K ea Linux extended boot

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:250GB:scsi:512:512:msdos:ATA Samsung SSD 850:;
1:1049kB:125GB:125GB:ntfs::;
2:125GB:250GB:125GB:::;
5:125GB:250GB:125GB:ext4::;
sdb:120GB:scsi:512:512:gpt:ATA SATA SSD:;
1:1049kB:106MB:105MB:fat32:EFI system partition:boot, esp;
2:106MB:240MB:134MB::Microsoft reserved partition:msftres;
3:369MB:57.1GB:56.7GB:ntfs:Microsoft basic data:msftdata;
4:57.1GB:120GB:63.0GB:ext4:Linux filesystem:;
sdc:8196MB:scsi:512:512:msdos:HEMA_8G HEMA_8GB:;
1:65.5kB:8196MB:8196MB:fat32::boot, lba;
2:8196MB:8196MB:32.3kB:::bls_boot;

Free space >10MiB: ______________________________________________________________

sdb: 229MiB:352MiB:123MiB

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME   FSTYPE   UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL       PARTLABEL
sda                                                                                                   
├─sda1 ntfs     6E5E2CFC5E2CBF29                     d039e563-01                          Data        
├─sda2                                               d039e563-02                                      
└─sda5 ext4     e910ec83-858c-4d12-b9e2-1e253113f69d d039e563-05                                      
sdb                                                                                                   
├─sdb1 vfat     2C44-0FFB                            c96eee69-b829-4c33-b6a0-529fd7aa0140 SYSTEM      EFI system partition
├─sdb2                                               c182b0e5-2393-4c5a-99fd-ee72f4e070f0             Microsoft reserved partition
├─sdb3 ntfs     AA4E7A834E7A4859                     ffa3bfea-b9ac-428c-9632-e2bee04e27ee Windows     Microsoft basic data
└─sdb4 ext4     31593fa6-7183-49a1-8c29-fc4d2fb78d37 be3829b6-7bbe-44cf-b7fb-bc270116001c             Linux filesystem
sdc                                                                                                   
├─sdc1 vfat     4C2C-8777                            0077d54e-01                          BOOT-REPAIR 
└─sdc2                                               0077d54e-02                                      

Mount points (filtered): _______________________________________________________

            Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1   77.5G  33% /mnt/boot-sav/sda1
/dev/sda5   26.6G  72% /mnt/boot-sav/sda5
/dev/sdb1   58.3M  39% /mnt/boot-sav/sdb1
/dev/sdb3    4.7G  91% /mnt/boot-sav/sdb3
/dev/sdb4    3.3G  89% /mnt/boot-sav/sdb4
/dev/sdc1    5.2G  32% /cdrom

Mount options (filtered): ______________________________________________________

/dev/sda1   fuseblk         ro,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
/dev/sda5   ext4            rw,relatime
/dev/sdb1   vfat            rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro
/dev/sdb3   fuseblk         ro,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
/dev/sdb4   ext4            rw,relatime,stripe=32716
/dev/sdc1   vfat            ro,noatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro

===================== sdb1/efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

search.fs_uuid 31593fa6-7183-49a1-8c29-fc4d2fb78d37 root hd1,gpt4 
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg

====================== sdb4/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

Windows Boot Manager (on sdb1)   osprober-efi-2C44-0FFB
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
UEFI Firmware Settings   uefi-firmware
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

========================== sdb4/etc/fstab (filtered) ===========================

# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sdb5 during installation
UUID=31593fa6-7183-49a1-8c29-fc4d2fb78d37 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /home was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=e910ec83-858c-4d12-b9e2-1e253113f69d /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
/dev/disk/by-uuid/6E5E2CFC5E2CBF29 /mnt/6E5E2CFC5E2CBF29 ntfs-3g uid=rgr,gid=users,umask=0022,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
UUID=2C44-0FFB  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1

======================= sdb4/etc/default/grub (filtered) =======================

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false

==================== sdb4: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
            ?? = ??             boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1
  71.478885651 = 76.749869056   boot/grub/i386-pc/core.img                     1
 107.459957123 = 115.384250368  boot/vmlinuz                                  35
 101.949405670 = 109.467340800  boot/vmlinuz-6.2.0-39-generic                  2
 107.459957123 = 115.384250368  boot/vmlinuz-6.5.0-44-generic                 35
 101.949405670 = 109.467340800  boot/vmlinuz.old                               2
  74.272335052 = 79.749312512   boot/initrd.img                               50
 100.582042694 = 107.999145984  boot/initrd.img-6.2.0-39-generic              28
  74.272335052 = 79.749312512   boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-44-generic              50
 100.582042694 = 107.999145984  boot/initrd.img.old                           28

===================== sdb4: ls -l /etc/grub.d/ (filtered) ======================

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 18228 Mar 21  2024 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 43202 Mar 21  2024 10_linux_zfs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 14459 Mar 21  2024 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   786 Mar 21  2024 25_bli
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 13120 Mar 21  2024 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1174 Mar 21  2024 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   722 Feb 26  2023 35_fwupd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   214 Jun 14  2017 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   215 Apr 15  2022 41_custom

====================== sdc1/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

Start Boot-Repair-Disk 64-bit
Start Boot-Repair-Disk 64-bit (compatibility mode)
UEFI Firmware Settings
Test memory

========================= sdc1/syslinux.cfg (filtered) =========================

DEFAULT loadconfig

LABEL loadconfig
  CONFIG /isolinux/isolinux.cfg
  APPEND /isolinux/

==================== sdc1: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
            ?? = ??             boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1

================== sdc1: Location of files loaded by Syslinux ==================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
            ?? = ??             syslinux.cfg                                   1
            ?? = ??             ldlinux.sys                                    1

Any help would be greatly appreciated. If you could explain to me what is going wrong and how I could fix it: great!
